# How to configure Vite.js to pre-bundle a NPM dependency as a single module or a chunk?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vite

Vite.js clearly mentions this in their dependency [pre-bundling](https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html) section about generating single module when there are multiple internal modules (i.e. deep imports):

> Vite converts ESM dependencies with many internal modules into a single module to improve subsequent page load performance.

> Some packages ship their ES modules builds as many separate files importing one another. For example, lodash-es has over 600 internal modules! When we do `import { debounce } from 'lodash-es'`, the browser fires off 600+ HTTP requests at the same time! Even though the server has no problem handling them, the large amount of requests create a network congestion on the browser side, causing the page to load noticeably slower.
> By pre-bundling `lodash-es` into a single module, we now only need one HTTP request instead!

Now, I have a similar library that contains SVGs and using the [`vite-plugin-svgr`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-svgr), I am converting them to the React components. It has close to 1000 icons. However, when I load my app in the browser, it ends up sending 800 network requests (1 for each SVG icon). Ideally, it should have simply pre-bundled the entire package into a single module request but it doesn't seem to be doing that.

As per [documentation](https://vitejs.dev/config/dep-optimization-options.html#optimizedeps-include), I even specified the library in the optimization section:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  // ... other config
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: [
      '@myorg/svg-icons/**/*.svg',
    ],
  }
});
```

But this does not have any effect! This causes my browser to slow down, specifically the network inspector on both Firefox and Chrome. Is there any way I can configure Vite.js to send a single module request for this library instead of 800 individual requests?